# Django: How to automatically generate the USERNAME_FIELD of a custom user model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is a learning project and I've been trying to create a custom user model with the possibility of having multiple accounts with the same *nickname*. The `USERNAME_FIELD` would be `username = f"{nickname}#{random_number}"` (just like the Blizzard and Discord format), but I can't figure out at which step I should include the function that would automatically create the username.

I tried generating the username in the `CustomAccountManager.create_user()` method but it doesn't seem to be called while filling the `RegistrationForm` from the view and it fails to create the superuser with `manage.py createsuperuser` (`TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'`). I'd be glad if someone could explain how to procede in this case or link a resource, I couldn't find one with this kind of example. Any additional insight on the code will be appreciated.

I have registered the model in admin.py with `admin.site.register(Account)`, included the accounts app in the settings and set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'`

account/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from random import randint
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

### ACCOUNT
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, nick, password = None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email was not provided during user creation. (account/models.py/CustomAccountManager.create_user)")
        if not nick:
            raise ValueError("Username was not provided during user creation. (account/models.py/CustomAccountManager.create_user)")
        if len(nick) >= 20:
            raise ValueError("Username cannot be longer than 20 characters")
        
        user_id = self.generate_id(nick)

        user = self.model(
            nick     = nick,
            username = f"{nick}#{user_id}",
            user_id  = user_id,
            email    = self.normalize_email(email),
            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, nick, email, password = None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email       = self.normalize_email(email),
            nick        = nick,
            password    = password,
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user
        
    def generate_id(self, nick: str) -> int: # I want this to be a random number
        database = []
        accounts = self.model.objects.filter(nick = nick)
        if len(accounts) > 995:
            raise ValueError("Cannot create an account with this username, please choose another one. (account/models.py/CustomAccountManager.generate_id)")

        for account in accounts:
            database.append(int(getattr(account, "user_id")))
        while True:
            potential_id = randint(0, 999)
            if potential_id not in database:
                return potential_id


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    ### PERSONAL INFO
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)
    second_name     = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank = True, null = True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)
    ### FUNCTIONAL PERSONAL INFO
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length = 60)                                        #/#
    username        = models.CharField(max_length = 25, unique = True)                          #/# = f"{self.nick}#{self.user_id}"
    nick            = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = "")
    user_id         = models.IntegerField(default = 777)
    
    ### FUNCTIONAL DJANGO
    USERNAME_FIELD  = "username"                                                                #/#
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email",]
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default = True)                                       #/#
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default = False)                                      #/#
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default = False)                                      #/#
    is_superuser    = models.BooleanField(default = False)                                      #/#
    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    ### LOGS
    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True) #when account was made
    last_login      = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)                           #/#
    rehabilitate    = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True) #date when user gets unbanned
    banned_amount   = models.IntegerField(default = 0) #collective hours banned
    banned_times    = models.IntegerField(default = 0) #amount of times someone was banned
    logins          = models.JSONField(default = dict)
    logouts         = models.JSONField(default = dict)
    bans            = models.JSONField(default = dict)
    unbans          = models.JSONField(default = dict)

    ### PERMISSIONS - REQUIRED
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj) -> bool:
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label) -> bool:
        return self.is_admin
```

account/views.py:

```
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, get_user_model
from account.forms import RegistrationForm
from account.models import Account

def RegistrationView(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/registration.html', context)
```

account/forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import Account

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model =     Account
        fields =    ("email", "nick", 'password1', 'password2',
                     "first_name", "second_name", "last_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have overwritten the `save()` method in the Account model this way:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not int(self.user_id):
            self.user_id = self.generate_id(self.nick) # moved from CustomAccountManager class
            self.username = f"{self.nick}#{self.user_id}"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm still not sure this is the best way, but it seems to work.